# AutoLayout and UITableView: how to adjust for Tabbar?

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, uitableview, autolayout

I have an UITableViewController which is embedded in a TabbarController which in turn is embedded in a UINavigationController. Now, the scrollview of the tableview scrolls the first 2 rows under the navigation bar on the top. See screenshot:
[image]

How can I adjust that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `navigationBar.translucent = NO;` in your `viewDidLoad`.

This happens due to the transparency feature that they introduced on iOS 7.

There's also another way:
Unchecking the "Under Top Bars" in the storyboard will also fix the issue (select the view controller)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(64.0,0.0,44.0,0.0);
```

This did the trick for me (in viewDidLoad)

Comment: If you use a different device, this might become different. Giving explicit size is not recommended by apple.

Comment: have a look at my answer.

Comment: @P.Sami based on your answer: `self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;` does work ;-)

Comment: This is the only working answer I could find. I wanted to have a uitableview inside a uiscrollview with a translucent tab bar. Thanks!